# Embedding MySql query in Excel, varchar column

Tags: mysql, excel-2003

I'm trying to embed mysql queries into excel and I've been mostly successful so far.  I'm using the odbc and Import Data External.............From a database query.

Problem is that when I return text columns they show in the query and in the msquery browser but they won't return to the sheet.  How do I have text columns return do the sheet using this method.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was having was resolved by typecasting as a varchar.  Excel got confused because I was using {concat, dayname} functions.